# constantly getting the same error code no matter what i try

Tags: javascript, function, boolean, return

I've wrote a code to solve a problem for a course I'm doing. It looks good to me but keeps giving me the same error code. I've tried a few different ways and still get the same thing.

This is the scenario:

> It's time to see if we can host our party!
>
> Before the party is confirmed, the shareholders need two criteria to
> be met:
>
> - At least 5 people must be in attendance
> - At least £100 must be generated via pay-what-you-want ticket sales
> - The isPartyViable function will be called with an array of guest objects. Each of those objects has a paidForTicket property with a
>   number representing how much they are willing to pay for their ticket.
>
> It should return a boolean value of false if not enough people are
> attending or attendees don't spend enough money on tickets, and true
> if enough people are attending and they spend enough money on tickets.

This is my code;

```
function isPartyViable(guests) {
    let totalMoney = 0;
    let totalGuests = 0;

    for (let key in guests){
        totalMoney += guests[key].paidForTickets
        totalGuests += 1
    }
    if (totalMoney >= 100 && totalGuests >= 5 ){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

This is the feedback I'm getting;

> 3 Passing 1 Failing
>
> Returns false when not enough guests are in attendance
>
> ```
> ✓  Well done!
> ```
>
> Returns false when not enough guests are in attendance, even if they
> raise sufficient funds
>
> ```
> ✓  Well done!
> ```
>
> Returns false when not enough money is raised from ticket sales
>
> ```
> ✓  Well done!
> ```
>
> Returns true when there are enough guests and enough money is raised
>
> ```
> ✕ AssertionError: expected false to equal true
> ```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question about your code. Also take the [tour].

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

The problem state that each guest has a `paidForTicket` property, while your code checks for `paidForTickets` (extra 's'), which is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

```js
if (totalMoney >= 100 && totalGuests >= 5 ){
        return true
    }
    return false
    }
```

You didn't include an "else" after the if statement, so the function would just always return false no matter what

```js
if (totalMoney >= 100 && totalGuests >= 5 ){
        return true
    } else {
    return false
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between two codes.
Because this `if` and `else` statement only return `true` or `false` value.